# Import data from the api URL (for example from Google Analytics) to clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Using curl the url to import data from Google's API, for example to Google Analytics, you can use this URL to get data

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?access_token=[YOUR_TOKEN]&ids=ga%3A[ID_GA_VIEW]&dimensions=ga%3Adate&metrics=ga%3Ausers&start-date=2021-12-01&end-date=2021-12-10'
```

This return me a JSON

```
"totalsForAllResults": {
    "ga:users": "214377"
  },
  "rows": [
    [
      "20211201",
      "28818"
    ],
    [
      "20211202",
      "27421"
    ],
    [
      "20211203",
      "23758"
    ],
    [
      "20211204",
      "12453"
    ],
    [
      "20211205",
      "12514"
    ],
    [
      "20211206",
      "21857"
    ],
    [
      "20211207",
      "23770"
    ],
    [
      "20211208",
      "17458"
    ],
    [
      "20211209",
      "24278"
    ],
    [
      "20211210",
      "22050"
    ]
  ]
```

Could I import to clickhouse using data directly from the url of the api?

Desired result, inserting data into table dirctly from API URL

| date | users |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-01 | 28818 |
| 2021-12-02 | 27421 |
| 2021-12-03 | 23758 |
| 2021-12-04 | 12453 |
| .... | .... |

Comment: Click house is a column oriented so your data won't look like that.  https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-schema-design/altinity-kb-jsonasstring-and-mat.-view-as-json-parser/

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/jsonextract-to-parse-many-attributes-at-a-time/

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/url/

Comment: I believe the first step is to try to import JSONAsString from the API URL https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-schema-design/altinity-kb-jsonasstring-and-mat.-view-as-json-parser/#:~:text=create%20table%20entrypoint(J%20String)%20Engine%3DNull%3B  

And, next,, extract values for each key.

I will try it and if I succeed I will share it here, thanks! :)